# npm module for ActiveMQ calls

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic

What is the best npm library to make ActiveMQ calls from nodejs? I've tried 'stomp' but sometimes it acts wired.
Whenever I use stomp port (61613) it worked
but when I use tcp port (61616) it throws an exception in ActiveMQ logs saying packet size is max out.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe as "weird" is the behavior I would expect.  The listener on port 61616 in ActiveMQ 5.x is for OpenWire clients and therefore not suitable for STOMP clients.  If you use a STOMP transportConnector then you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: You are correct about the issue. But you do not need Artemis for multiple protocols per transport. `<transportConnector name="auto" uri="auto://localhost:61616"/>` would allow STOMP, MQTT, OpenWire and AMQP on the same port from version 5.13.0.